# jTree in jComboBox not automatically resizing when expanding a branch node

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtree, jpopupmenu

I am attempting to fix a bug in our Java Swing program that affects our dropdown boxes. The tree indicates file hierarchy, with branch nodes being folders and leaf nodes being files. Some of the file names are quite long and as such, the dropdown menu should resize whenever a folder node is expanded to reveal long file names. However, the *first time* (and *only* the first time) a folder node is expanded, the dropdown menu will not resize to accommodate the newly revealed content. If you close the menu and reopen it, or even just collapse and reopen the folder node, the menu will resize. The resizing code is as follows, and does in fact run every time the dropdown or a branch node is opened/closed.

```
protected void updatePopup() {
    int comboWidth = c_comboBox.getWidth() + 1;
    int popupWidth = (int) c_tree.getPreferredSize().getWidth();
    int width = Math.max(comboWidth, popupWidth);

    int height = (int) c_tree.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().getHeight() * 2;

    c_popup.setPopupSize(width, height);
    setPopupSize(width + 10, height);
    ...
}
```

I am curious as to why the dropdown isn't resizing properly when nodes are initially loaded, but does so properly if the nodes are closed and reopened. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I will continue to research in the mean time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I will try to formulate my question this way and then edit. My first stackoverflow question, asking good questions is a skill just like anything else!